# JavaScript missing parametar

Tags: javascript, json, session, moodle

I am coding a block type plugin for Moodle and have this JS code that gives me problems. Since I'm not very familiar with JS and JSON I can't deduce what is the problem.
My code uses this function to add custom action to action link which issues ajax call to php file ...

This is the code:

```
function block_helpdesk_sendemail(e) {

e.preventDefault();

Y.log('Enetered method');

var sess = {'sesskey=':M.cfg.sesskey};
Y.log(sess);

var ioconfig = {
    method: 'GET',
    data: {'sesskey=':M.cfg.sesskey},
    on: {
        success: function (o, response) {
          //OK
          var data;
          try {
            data = Y.JSON.parse(response.responseText);

            Y.log("RAW JSON DATA: " + data);

          } catch (e) {
            alert("JSON Parse failed!");
            Y.log("JSON Parse failed!");
            return;
          }
          if (data.result) {
            alert('Result is OK!');
            Y.log('Success');
          }
        },
        failure: function (o, response) {
          alert('Not OK!');
          Y.log('Failure');
        }
     }
};

Y.io(M.cfg.wwwroot + '/blocks/helpdesk/sendmail.php', ioconfig);
}
```

The code pauses in debugger at return line:

```
Y.namespace('JSON').parse = function (obj, reviver, space) {
    return _JSON.parse((typeof obj === 'string' ? obj : obj + ''), reviver, space);
};
```

I've put M.cfg.sesskey and data variables on watch. I can see sesskey data shown, but data variable shows like this:

```
data: Object
  debuginfo: "Error code: missingparam"
  error: "A required parameter (sesskey) was missing"
  reproductionlink: "http://localhost:8888/moodle/"
  stacktrace: "* line 463 of /lib/setuplib.php: moodle_exception thrown
               * line 545 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to print_error()
               * line 70 of /lib/sessionlib.php: call to required_param()
               * line 7 of /blocks/helpdesk/sendmail.php: call to confirm_sesskey()"
```

And this is what my logs show:

```
Enetered method
Object {sesskey=: "J5iSJS7G99"}
RAW JSON DATA: [object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your declaring `sesskey` in a bizarre way.

try replacing `data: {'sesskey=':M.cfg.sesskey},`

with `data: {sesskey: M.cfg.sesskey},`

it might be worth you reading through this
[mdn link for javascript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

You usually need to `JSON.stringify()` the objects sent via ajax. 
which may be part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you both @codefan. I've tried both solutions (in quotes and no quotes) and now I'm getting JSON parse failed error. I will read the link that Collet89 provided and hopefully solve the problem

Comment: @Moirae glad you have got a little further. You usually need to `JSON.stringify()` the objects sent via ajax. which may be part of the problem.

Comment: Could you add that to your previous answer so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: @Moirae done. Glad to be of help (its been a while since I did JavaScript AJAX requests - glad my knowledge is still there!)

Answer (score 2):

As @Collett89 said, the JSON definition is wrong. His tip might work, but if you need strict JSON data then code the key as string (with quotes):

```
var sess = {'sesskey': M.cfg.sesskey};
```

or

```
var sess = {"sesskey": M.cfg.sesskey};
```

[See definition in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)